# R: How to use grep() to find specific words?

Tags: r, regex

I have a long data frame with words. I want to use multi specific words to find each all part-of-speech words.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(word = c("clean", "grinding liquid cmp", "cleaning", 
                          "cleaning composition", "supplying", "supply", "supplying cmp 
                          abrasive", "chemical mechanical"))

words
1 clean
2 grinding liquid cmp
3 cleaning
4 cleaning composition
5 supplying
6 supply
7 supplying cmp abrasive
8 chemical mechanical
```

I want to extract "clean" and "supply" single words with different POS. I have tried use the `grep()` function to do.

```
specific_word <- c("clean", "supply")

grep_onto <- df_1[grepl(paste(ontoword_apparatus, collapse = "|"), df_1$word), ] %>%
    data.frame(word = ., row.names = NULL) %>%
    unique()
```

But the result is not what I want:

```
  word
1 cleans
2 grinding liquid cmp
3 cleaning
4 cleaning composition
5 supplying
6 supply
7 supplying cmp abrasive
8 chemical mechanical
```

I  prefer to get

```
words
1 clean
2 cleaning
3 supplying
4 supply
```

I know maybe regular expression can solve my problem, but I don't know how to define it. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Take a look at `str_extract` in the `stringr` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, but generally if you want it to be a single word and you're using regex, you need to specify the beginning `^` and end `$` of the line so as to limit what can come before or after your pattern. You seem to want it to be able to expand with more letters, so add in `\\w*` to allow it:

```r
df <- data.frame(word = c("clean", "grinding liquid cmp", "cleaning", 
                          "cleaning composition", "supplying", "supply", 
                          "supplying cmp abrasive", "chemical mechanical"))

specific_word <- c("clean", "supply")
pattern <- paste0('^\\w*', specific_word, '\\w*$', collapse = '|')

pattern
#> [1] "^\\w*clean\\w*$|^\\w*supply\\w*$"

df[grep(pattern, df$word), , drop = FALSE]    # drop = FALSE to stop simplification to vector
#>        word
#> 1     clean
#> 3  cleaning
#> 5 supplying
#> 6    supply
```

Another interpretation of what you're looking for is to split each term into individual words, and search any of those for a match. `tidyr::separate_rows` can be used for such a split, which you can then `filter` with `grepl`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(word = c("clean", "grinding liquid cmp", "cleaning", 
                          "cleaning composition", "supplying", "supply", 
                          "supplying cmp abrasive", "chemical mechanical"))

specific_word <- c("clean", "supply")

df %>% separate_rows(word) %>%
    filter(grepl(paste(specific_word, collapse = '|'), word)) %>% 
    distinct()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>        word
#>       <chr>
#> 1     clean
#> 2  cleaning
#> 3 supplying
#> 4    supply
```

For more robust word tokenization, try `tidytext::unnest_tokens` or another word actual word tokenizer.